# Cant echo topics in Ros2 ubunbu 22

Tags: ros2

I have been trying to echo a topic from labview from my other computer.
I type out `ros2 topic echo /rosint`, it always seems to return

```
The message type 'ros2labview_example2/msg/Myint' is invalid.
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()


find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
    "msg/Myint.msg"
    "msg/Clusterdemo.msg"
    )

rosidl_get_typesupport_target(cpp_typesupport_target ${PROJECT_NAME} "rosidl_typesupport_cpp")

add_executable(sub_int32 src/sub_int32.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(sub_int32 rclcpp std_msgs)

add_executable(pub_int32 src/pub_int32.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(pub_int32 rclcpp std_msgs)

add_executable(add_int src/add_int.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(add_int rclcpp std_msgs)

add_executable(sub_custom_int src/sub_custom_int.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(sub_custom_int rclcpp std_msgs)
target_link_libraries(sub_custom_int ${cpp_typesupport_target})

add_executable(pub_custom_int src/pub_custom_int.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(pub_custom_int rclcpp std_msgs)
target_link_libraries(pub_custom_int ${cpp_typesupport_target})

add_executable(sub_cluster src/sub_cluster.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(sub_cluster rclcpp std_msgs)
target_link_libraries(sub_cluster ${cpp_typesupport_target})

add_executable(pub_cluster src/pub_cluster.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(pub_cluster rclcpp std_msgs)
target_link_libraries(pub_cluster ${cpp_typesupport_target})


install(TARGETS
sub_int32
pub_int32
add_int
sub_custom_int
pub_custom_int
sub_cluster
pub_cluster
DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

`package.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>ros2labview_example2</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="david@todo.todo">david</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>
  
  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

`sub_custom_int.cpp`

```
#include<memory>

#include"rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include"ros2labview_example2/msg/myint.hpp"



#define be RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT


class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    MinimalSubscriber()
    : Node("cint_sub"),
    best_effort(rclcpp::KeepLast(10))
    {
        subscription_ = this->create_subscription<ros2labview_example2::msg::Myint>(
        "clabint", best_effort.reliability(be), [this](const ros2labview_example2::msg::Myint::SharedPtr msg){
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: %ld", msg->num);
        });
    }
    
private:
    rclcpp::Subscription<ros2labview_example2::msg::Myint>::SharedPtr subscription_;
    rclcpp::QoS best_effort;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

`Myint.msg`

```
int64 num
```

Comment: @ssarkar - Useful tip: Instead of having to add 4 spaces at the start of *each* line (which is a pain to do), it is *much* quicker to code fence using `\`\`\`...\`\`\``. Also, if you use spaces you can't really specify a language, whereas with code fencing you could do `\`\`\`python...\`\`\`` or `\`\`\`cpp...\`\`\``, etc.. Please see [markdown_supported_languages](https://github.com/jincheng9/markdown_supported_languages) for more info :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like to me, I can see that you have required `std_msgs` as a dependency in your `CMakeLists.txt`, but you haven't specified it in your `rosidl_generate_interfaces` as a dependency for your datatypes. A correct example of the `rosidl_generate_interfaces` might look like this.

```
# generate code for message types by manually specifying 
# all the message types and their dependencies
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
   msg/Myint.msg
   msg/Clusterdemo.msg
   DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
)
```

You are also missing an important line in your `CMakeLists.txt` that allows any package using your custom messages, to do so seamlessly.

```
# rest of your ROS 2 CMakeLists.txt code

# ensures that any package using your custom
# messages can do so seamlessly
ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)

ament_package()
```

You seem to have the right dependencies in your `package.xml`.

```xml
<depend>rclcpp</depend>
<depend>std_msgs</depend>

<depend>rosidl_default_generators</depend>
<depend>rosidl_default_runtime</depend>

<member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
```

Looking at your `sub_custom_int.cpp` code, everything seems fine at first glance. However, you are saying that you are using the command `ros2 topic echo /rosint` but your `sub_custom_int.cpp` file seems to be subscribing to the `clabint` instead. Could you provide more information concerning this?

If you are looking for good examples of custom message datatype implementations in a ROS 2 project, I recommend you have a look at the [px4_msgs](https://github.com/PX4/px4_msgs) (examples of custom messages) and [px4_ros_com](https://github.com/PX4/px4_ros_com) (examples of using the custom messages) GitHub repositories.

Comment: My programing is subscribing to the labview program custom lab integer Clabint

also i have added your line of  "ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)" but it seems to come up with :

CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:93 (message):
  rosidl_generate_interfaces() the passed file 'DEPENDENCIES std_msgs'
  doesn't exist relative to the CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR
  '/home/david/ros2_example_ws/src/ros2labview_example2'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


any idea why th

Comment: this happens? also it says :
gmake: *** [Makefile:1250: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
---
Failed   <<< ros2labview_example2 [0.67s, exited with code 2]

Comment: It could be due to a couple of reasons. 
1. I would advise you to check if your directory structure is correct and that your `.msg` files are in the `src/your_package/msg` directory.
2. Try changing the `exec_depend` and `build_depend` tags for the `rosidl_default_generators` and `rosidl_default_runtime` to just `depend` for the time being.
3.  The `ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)` should be placed after your `find_packages()` and `rosidl_generate_interfaces()` calls, so ensure you have done that.
4. Make sure you are sourcing your ROS 2 environment.

Comment: the program worked now thank you so much!